# Sharing viewModel within Jetpack Compose Navigation

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation

Can anyone suggest how to share a ViewModel within different sections of a Jetpack Compose Navigation?

According to the documentation, viewModels should normally be shared within different compose functions using the activity scope, but not if inside the navigation.

Here is the code I am trying to fix. It looks like I am getting two different viewModels here in two sections inside the navigation:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            NavigationSystem()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NavigationSystem() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home") {
        composable("home") { HomeScreen(navController) }
        composable("result") { ResultScreen(navController) }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val viewModel: ConversionViewModel = viewModel()
    
    var temp by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val fahrenheit = temp.toIntOrNull() ?: 0

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Column {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = temp,
                onValueChange = { temp = it },
                label = { Text("Fahrenheit") },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.85f)
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp))

            Button(onClick = {
                Log.d("HomeScreen", fahrenheit.toString())
                if (fahrenheit !in 1..160) return@Button
                viewModel.onCalculate(fahrenheit)
                navController.navigate("result")
            }) {
                Text("Calculate")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ResultScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val viewModel: ConversionViewModel = viewModel()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Log.d("ResultScreenDebug", "celsius: ${ viewModel.celsius.value.toString()}")
        Text(
            viewModel.celsius.value.toString(),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 24.dp))

        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("home") }) {
            Text(text = "Calculate again")
        }
    }
}
```

Debug log:

```
2021-07-27 22:01:52.542 27113-27113/com.example.navigation D/ViewModelDebug: fh: 65, cs: 18, celcius: 18.0
2021-07-27 22:01:52.569 27113-27113/com.example.navigation D/ResultScreenDebug: celsius: 0.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: A good way to share business logic accross view models and avoid redundancy would be to use "Use cases" from the domain layer. Read more in https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/domain-layer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could create a viewModel and pass it trough

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            NavigationSystem()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NavigationSystem() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    val viewModel: ConversionViewModel = viewModel()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home") {
        composable("home") { HomeScreen(navController, viewModel) }
        composable("result") { ResultScreen(navController, viewModel) }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavController, viewModel: ConversionViewModel) {
    var temp by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val fahrenheit = temp.toIntOrNull() ?: 0

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Column {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = temp,
                onValueChange = { temp = it },
                label = { Text("Fahrenheit") },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.85f)
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp))

            Button(onClick = {
                Log.d("HomeScreen", fahrenheit.toString())
                if (fahrenheit !in 1..160) return@Button
                viewModel.onCalculate(fahrenheit)
                navController.navigate("result")
            }) {
                Text("Calculate")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ResultScreen(navController: NavController, viewModel: ConversionViewModel) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Log.d("ResultScreenDebug", "celsius: ${ viewModel.celsius.value.toString()}")
        Text(
            viewModel.celsius.value.toString(),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 24.dp))

        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("home") }) {
            Text(text = "Calculate again")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks a million! I was asking this question everywhere, but no one seems to know the answer yet. I hope this thread will help many others in the future.

Comment: Also a side question: I tried to initialize the view model in onCreate() of the activity and pass it to the main compose function, but it shows an error if I try to initialize it there like this: `val viewModel: ConversionViewModel = viewModel()`. Can you please explain why?

Comment: You have to put the function in setContent { } because `=viewmodel` is a Composable function, so it needs to be called from a composable scope.

Comment: While this solution works, it seems like the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/compose-in-existing-arch) says that this approach is a no-go:
`You should never pass down ViewModel instances to other composables, pass only the data they need and functions that perform the required logic as parameters.`

Comment: @BenjyTec Does that mean each composable should have their own ViewModel?

Answer (score 27):

Consider passing your activity to viewModel() fun as viewModelStoreOwner parameter since ComponentActivity implements ViewModelStoreOwner interface:

```
val viewModel: ConversionViewModel = viewModel(LocalContext.current as ComponentActivity)
```

This code will return the same instance of ConversionViewModel in all your destinations.

Comment: Passing acitivity to the view model is a bad pattern. These two should always be separated.

Comment: @ShadeToD I'm not passing activity instance to the ViewModel constructor, I'm passing it to viewModel() fun as an instance of ViewModelStoreOwner.

Comment: If you rotated the phone data would viewmodel data be retained?

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helped, it works the same as `val viewModel by activityViewModels<ConversionViewModel>()` to use one instance between fragments.

Answer (score 13):

I think a better solution, than scopes your `ViewModel` to your entire `NavGraph` is to build the `ViewModel` in the `Home` route and then access from the `Result` route (route scoped):

```kotlin
//extensions
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> NavBackStackEntry?.viewModel(): T? = this?.let {
    viewModel(viewModelStoreOwner = it)
}

@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> NavBackStackEntry.viewModel(
    viewModelStoreOwner: ViewModelStoreOwner = checkNotNull(LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current) {
        "No ViewModelStoreOwner was provided via LocalViewModelStoreOwner"
    }
): T {
    return androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel(
        viewModelStoreOwner = viewModelStoreOwner, key = T::class.java.name
    )
}

//use-case
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val viewModel: ConversionViewModel = viewModel()
    ...
}
@Composable
fun ResultScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val viewModel: ConversionViewModel? = navController.previousBackStackEntry.viewModel()
    ...
}
```

But if you must to scope it to the entire `NavGraph`, you can do something like the @akhris said, but in a way that you could uncouple the `ViewModelStoreOwner` from the `Activity`:

```kotlin
//composable store-owner builder
@Composable
fun rememberViewModelStoreOwner(): ViewModelStoreOwner {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    return remember(context) { context as ViewModelStoreOwner }
}
```

This way you uncouple the `Activity` from your `ViewModelStoreOwner` and can do something like:

```kotlin
val LocalNavGraphViewModelStoreOwner =
    staticCompositionLocalOf<ViewModelStoreOwner> {
        TODO("Undefined")
    }

@Composable
fun NavigationSystem() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val vmStoreOwner = rememberViewModelStoreOwner()

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalNavGraphViewModelStoreOwner provides vmStoreOwner
    ) {
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home") {
            composable("home") { HomeScreen(navController) }
            composable("result") { ResultScreen(navController) }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val viewModel: ConversionViewModel = viewModel(viewModelStoreOwner = LocalNavGraphViewModelStoreOwner.current)
    ...
}

@Composable
fun ResultScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val viewModel: ConversionViewModel = viewModel(viewModelStoreOwner = LocalNavGraphViewModelStoreOwner.current)
    ...
}
```

Comment: cleanest so far! thanks

Comment: Cool this should be an official implementation I hope, thanks @YehezkielL

Comment: This looks clean. But lets say I'm on my HomeScreen, navigate to the SecondScreen, and what ever selected on SecondScreen should be accessible from the HomeScreen in the viewModel.

Answer (score 8):

A [recommended approach](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation), if you want to access the **ViewModel scoped to navigation routes or the navigation graph** i.e. that is shared between navigation routes or the navigation graph, you should use:

```kotlin
@Composable 
fun MyApp() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val startRoute = "example"
    val innerStartRoute = "exampleWithRoute"
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = startRoute) {
        navigation(startDestination = innerStartRoute, route = "Parent") {
            composable("exampleWithRoute") { backStackEntry ->
                //IMPORTANT PART: getting the scoped ViewModel reference.

                val parentEntry = remember(backStackEntry) {
                    navController.getBackStackEntry("Parent")
                }
                val parentViewModel = hiltViewModel<ParentViewModel>(parentEntry)

                ExampleWithRouteScreen(parentViewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make it easier, you may use the following extension functions might be useful:

```kotlin
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> NavBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(
    navController: NavController,
): T {
    val navGraphRoute = destination.parent?.route ?: return viewModel()
    val parentEntry  = remember(this){
        navController.getBackStackEntry(navGraphRoute)
    }
    return viewModel(parentEntry)
}
```

Then you can simply call inside your composable route:

```kotlin
val parentViewModel = backStackEntry.sharedViewModel<ParentViewModel>(navController)
```

You may also want to watch this [Philipp Lackner's video on the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIEnIBq7Ups).

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: What are the implications of returning hiltViewModel() if the parent's route is null? e.g val navGraphRoute = destination.parent?.route ?: return hiltViewModel()

Answer (score -2):

Is this not good enough?

Get the sharedViewModel at the top MainScreen and pass it explicitly. It doesn't seem to cause any memory leaks.

```kotlin
// MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MainScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Navigation(navController, sharedViewModel)
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
// Navigation.kt
fun Navigation(navController: NavHostController, sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel) {
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = "Home") {
        composable("Home") {
            EpisodeListScreen(navController, sharedViewModel)
        }
        composable("Login") {
            LoginScreen(navController, sharedViewModel)
        }
        composable("Editor") {
            EditorScreen(navController, sharedViewModel)
        }
        composable("Setting") {
            SettingScreen(navController, sharedViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
// EpisodeListScreen.kt
@Composable
fun EpisodeListScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: in my opinion this is not clean way at all